# Laplacian Filter Formula

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

I tried Laplacian filter method but i think I did somethings wrong with its formula.

My original matrix (f)

```
  a b
a 1 2
b 3 4
```

New matrix (g) by padding old matrix and replicating the origial one for using 3x3 filter mask

```
  a b c d e f
a 1 2 1 2 1 2
b 3 4 3 4 3 4
c 1 2 1 2 1 2
d 3 4 3 4 3 4
e 1 2 1 2 1 2
f 3 4 3 4 3 4
```

The filter (m)

```
  a  b  c
a 0  1  0
b 1 -4  1
c 0  1  0
```

Then I start at [c,c] in the new matrix. What I did in the calculation was

g(c,c) = g (c,c) + -1* (m(a,a)*g(b,b) + m(a,b)*g(b,c) + m(a,c)*g(b,d) + m(b,a)*g(c,b) + m(b,b)*g(c,c) + m(b,c)*g(c,d) + m(c,a)*g(d,b) + m(c,b)*g(d,c) + m(c,c)*g(d,d));

After performing the filter on g(c,c) , g(c,d) , g(d,c) , g (d,d), I crop the matrix as filtered these filter point to the new matrix, but the result look really weird. (not like in the book). I tried doing it in matlab by myself.

Can someday help me with this? Thank you very much

Comment: Applying a 3x3 filter to a 2x2 image doesn't really make a lot of sense - the result will be almost completely dominated by how you handle the edges, for which there are several different methods. Try using a more reasonably sized image, e.g. 8x8.

Comment: i just wrote like that for simple purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the same results as Nasser's method using conv2 and filter2 (which are only the same because your filter has symmetric rows), first you can't do it in-place. Previously filtered entries will mess up the subsequent calculations. Second, I'm not sure where that `g(c,c) + -1*` comes in. A normal filter calculation for g(c,c) would be:

```
r(c,c) = m(a,a)*g(b,b) + m(a,b)*g(b,c) + m(a,c)*g(b,d) +...
         m(b,a)*g(c,b) + m(b,b)*g(c,c) + m(b,c)*g(c,d) +...
         m(c,a)*g(d,b) + m(c,b)*g(d,c) + m(c,c)*g(d,d);
```

where r is the result matrix. This method (repeated for the other 3 values in the original matrix) gives:

```
r =
   c  d
c  6  2
d -2 -6
```

**UPDATE**

using:

```
A =
    1     2     1     2     1     2
    3     4     3     4     3     4
    1     2     1     2     1     2
    3     4     3     4     3     4
    1     2     1     2     1     2
    3     4     3     4     3     4

mask =
    0     1     0
    1    -4     1
    0     1     0
```

imfilter gives:

```
imfilter(A,mask)
ans =
    1    -2     3    -2     3    -3
   -6    -6    -2    -6    -2    -9
    4     2     6     2     6     1
   -6    -6    -2    -6    -2    -9
    4     2     6     2     6     1
   -7    -8    -3    -8    -3   -11
```

The function suggested above,

```
for i=1:2
    for j=1:2
        r(i,j) = m(1,1)*g(i+1,j+1) + m(1,2)*g(i+1,j+2) + m(1,3)*g(i+1,j+3) +...
                 m(2,1)*g(i+2,j+1) + m(2,2)*g(i+2,j+2) + m(2,3)*g(i+2,j+3) +...
                 m(3,1)*g(i+3,j+1) + m(3,2)*g(i+3,j+2) + m(3,3)*g(i+3,j+3);
    end
end
```

gives:

```
ans =
     6     2
    -2    -6
```

Does this match what you expect to see?

Note: The function above is not how I would implement it, but it follows the example that you gave for clarity.

Comment: g(c,c) + -1* is from the Laplacian formula... and the imfilter is similar to what I tried doing above, but it brings the incorrect result

Comment: @Aptos What results did you expect and what results did you get?

Comment: when using imfilter with above original matrix and mask, the ans is [3,1,-1,-3], when I applyign the above function, result is [0,0,0,255]

Comment: @Aptos See my answer for updates on the results I got. Also, can you post a link to the Laplace formula you're using?